# Return selectvalue as object from a bound option list in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I want to bind a key value object to an optionlist in knockout

```
function ParameterOption(name , value) { 
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
}
```

My select list

```
<select data-bind="
  options: Options, 
  value: SelectedValue,
  optionsText: 'name',
  attr :{'id':Id, 'name':Name}"></select>
```

I'm using cascading dropboxed so I need the option text to fetch the next list. 
When I submit the form I want to send the value.

This is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fJkh/3/) of what i've done so far.

My problem is that if i dont set `optionsValue` when i submit the form the parameters has no value. but, if i set `optionsValue : 'value'` i get the raw value in the model and not a `ParameterOption` object as i should.

Is there a way of binding the value to the option and still retrive an object as the selected value back to the model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `optionsAfterRender` parameter to set the `value` property of each option, giving the select box a text value when submitting, but not upsetting the object value used by Knockout:

```
optionsAfterRender: function(option, item) { option.value = item.value }
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7fJkh/4/

Reference: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html